# Grunt-contrib-copy temporary disable path filters

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

Hi I'm using this filter

```
var fs = require('fs');

function onlyNew(target) {
  return function(filepath) {
    var src = fs.statSync(filepath).mtime.getTime();
    var dest = grunt.config(target.concat('dest')) +
      filepath.slice(grunt.config(target.concat('cwd')).length);
    dest = fs.statSync(dest).mtime.getTime();
    return src > dest;
  }
};
```

in the following call to `grunt-contrib-copy`

```
copy: {
        all: {
            src: 'mysource/reset.html',
            dest: 'mydest/reset.html',
            filter: onlyNew(['copy', 'all'])
        },
},
```

This works great and only copies when the source file is newer than the destination. However how do I temporarily disable those filters to force a copy.

I attempted making the `onlyNew`` filter as such:

```
function onlyNew(target) {
  if (grunt.option('forceCopy'))
      return true;
  else {
      return function(filepath) {
        var src = fs.statSync(filepath).mtime.getTime();
        var dest = grunt.config(target.concat('dest')) +
          filepath.slice(grunt.config(target.concat('cwd')).length);
        dest = fs.statSync(dest).mtime.getTime();
        return src > dest;
      }
  }
};
```

However running `grunt --forceCopy` is having no effect

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand this, but my logic was inverted, this works:

```
function onlyNew(target) {
  if (grunt.option('forceCopy'))
      return false;
  else {
      return function(filepath) {
        var src = fs.statSync(filepath).mtime.getTime();
        var dest = grunt.config(target.concat('dest')) +
          filepath.slice(grunt.config(target.concat('cwd')).length);
        dest = fs.statSync(dest).mtime.getTime();
        return src > dest;
      }
  }
};
```